# Invalid column index during procedure execution

Tags: sql, procedures

Below is the Exception I got after invoking a stored procedure using spring JDBC template from Java.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call PKG_IBS_AC_CHANGE_API.P_UPDATE_ACCOUNT_CURRENCY(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [null]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:127)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreatorFactory$CallableStatementCreatorImpl.createCallableStatement(CallableStatementCreatorFactory.java:212)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(Jdb
```

So I ran the same code using spring DEBUG mode and below are few output from the logger.

```
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:57,503: CallMetaDataProvider - Retrieving metadata for PKG_IBS_AC_CHANGE_API/PPOKEROPS/P_UPDATE_ACCOUNT_CURRENCY
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,008: CallMetaDataProvider - Retrieved metadata: IN_ACCOUNT_NAME 1 12 VARCHAR2 true
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,011: CallMetaDataProvider - Retrieved metadata: IN_NEW_AC_TYPE 1 12 VARCHAR2 true
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,015: CallMetaDataProvider - Retrieved metadata: IN_SHOULD_COMMIT 1 1111 PL/SQL BOOLEAN true
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,019: CallMetaDataProvider - Retrieved metadata: OUT_ERROR_INFO 4 1111 PPOKEROPS.TYPE_BONUS_ERROR_INFO true
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,022: CallMetaDataProvider - Retrieved metadata: IN_SOURCE 1 12 VARCHAR2 true
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,025: CallMetaDataProvider - Retrieved metadata: IN_EVENT_TXN_ID 1 3 NUMBER true
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,029: CallMetaDataProvider - Retrieved metadata: IN_SOURCE_TYPE 1 12 VARCHAR2 true
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,032: CallMetaDataProvider - Retrieved metadata: OUT_OLD_ACCOUNT_INFO 4 1111 EZECASH.TYPE_USER_ACCOUNT_INFO true
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,036: CallMetaDataProvider - Retrieved metadata: OUT_NEW_ACCOUNT_INFO 4 1111 EZECASH.TYPE_USER_ACCOUNT_INFO true
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,040: DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,045: CallMetaDataContext - Using declared parameter for: IN_ACCOUNT_NAME
..............
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,053: SimpleJdbcCall - The following parameters are used for call {call PKG_IBS_AC_CHANGE_API.P_UPDATE_ACCOUNT_CURRENCY(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)} with: {in_source=source, in_source_type=sourcetype, in_event_txn_id=340, in_account_name=name, in_new_ac_type=USD, in_should_commit=0}
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,053: SimpleJdbcCall - 1: in_account_name SQL Type 12 Type Name null org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,053: SimpleJdbcCall - 2: in_new_ac_type SQL Type 12 Type Name null org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,053: SimpleJdbcCall - 3: in_should_commit SQL Type 1111 Type Name null org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,054: SimpleJdbcCall - 4: out_error_info SQL Type 1111 Type Name type_bonus_error_info org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,054: SimpleJdbcCall - 5: in_source SQL Type 12 Type Name null org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,054: SimpleJdbcCall - 6: in_event_txn_id SQL Type 3 Type Name null org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,054: SimpleJdbcCall - 7: in_source_type SQL Type 12 Type Name null org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,054: SimpleJdbcCall - 8: out_old_account_info SQL Type 1111 Type Name ezecash.TYPE_USER_ACCOUNT_INFO org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter
DEBUG:28-08-2013 17:55:58,054: SimpleJdbcCall - 9: out_new_account_info SQL Type 1111 Type Name ezecash.TYPE_USER_ACCOUNT_INFO org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter
```

Earlier the type values like 1111,12,3 etc were different for metadata and SimpleJDBC call. But I found the values and made the types same. Still there is some problem in setting the values.
Below is how I set the values

```
        parameters.put("in_account_name", "name");
        parameters.put("in_new_ac_type", toCurrency);
        parameters.put("in_should_commit", new Boolean(true));//I tried 0 and 1
        parameters.put("in_source", "source");
        parameters.put("in_event_txn_id", new BigDecimal(340.0));//tried 340.00 also
        parameters.put("in_source_type", "sourcetype");//these values are varchar
```

So can anyone help me to find out where exactly I went wrong and why i am getting invalid column index exception?

Comment: It might be because of the jar file.. make sure you have only one ojdbc.jar file in your class path

Comment: @sonic I have only one spring jar

Comment: Can you show us the data types of both your table columns and the data you are passing to them? Invalid column type is generally a mismatch between the data type being inserted and the column data type.

Comment: also show the code you are using to execute the procedure

Comment: @chad          :                                         SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(ppokeropsJDBCTemplate).withCatalogName("PKG name").withProcedureName("procedure").declareParameters(
new SqlParameter("account_name",OracleTypes.VARCHAR),new SqlParameter("ac_type", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),),
new SqlParameter("commit",OracleTypes.OTHER),
new SqlParameter("source", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
new SqlParameter("event_txn_id", OracleTypes.DECIMAL),
new SqlParameter("source_type", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),

Comment: @chad:Output params new SqlOutParameter("out_error_info",OracleTypes.OTHER),
new SqlOutParameter("out_old_account_info",OracleTypes.OTHER),
new SqlOutParameter("out_new_account_info",OracleTypes.OTHER)

Comment: @sonic Code is pasted above. Parameter values passed are in the question.

Comment: After Google-ing some, I think that you may need to check that your jdbc driver for Oracle is up-to-date. http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?52838-error-code-17004-when-insert-null